# Dataframe replace with another row, based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like the following:

```
    ean           product_resource_id        shop
----------------------------------------------------
    123           abc                        xxl
    245           bed                        xxl
    456           dce                        xxl
    123           0                          conr
    245           0                          horec
```

I want to replace `0 "product_resource_id"`s with an id where "`ean`"s are same.

I want to get a result like:

```
    ean           product_resource_id        shop
----------------------------------------------------
    123           abc                        xxl
    245           bed                        xxl
    456           dce                        xxl
    123           abc                        conr
    245           bed                        horec
```

Any help would be really helpful. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Idea is filter rows with `0` values in `product_resource_id`, remove duplicates by `ean` column if exist and create Series by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) for mapping, if no match values are replace by original by values by [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html), because non match values return `NaN`s:

```
#mask = df['product_resource_id'].ne('0')
#if 0 is integer
mask = df['product_resource_id'].ne(0)
s = df[mask].drop_duplicates('ean').set_index('ean')['product_resource_id']
df['product_resource_id'] = df['ean'].map(s).fillna(df['product_resource_id'])
print (df)
   ean product_resource_id   shop
0  123                 abc    xxl
1  245                 bed    xxl
2  456                 dce    xxl
3  123                 abc   conr
4  245                 bed  horec
```